# How do I use NSExpression with NSPredicate

Tags: nspredicate, absolute-value

I searched the whole internet but could not find any good explanation on how to use NSExpression in NSPredicate. I know that there's built in function abs which I need for my predicate. I have this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hg-%f<0.000001",[txtInput.text floatValue]];
```

I need absolute value of hg-[txtInput.text floatValue] part. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `abs( )` around the expression you want the absolute value of inside your predicate string

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"abs(hg-%f)<0.000001",[txtInput.text floatValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks David. I got very surprised when I saw it work as abs does not appear to be one of built in functions of NSPredicate. It rather is a function in NSExpression. From this I infer that we can use any NSExpression expressions in the NSPredicate string format part.

Comment: If you look at the BNF definition for Cocoa predicates (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html) you will see that you can use a set of functions inside the predicate string (sum, count, min, max, average, median, mode, stddev, sort, log, ln, exp, floor, ceiling, abs, trunc, random, randomn, now)